# Why is the padding calculated differently between <a> and <button> elements?

Tags: css

Why exactly is the padding calculated differently between `a` and `button` elements?

HTML

```
<button type="button">CLICK</button>
<a href="#">LINK</a>
```

CSS

```
button {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    line-height: 30px;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: you can attach a jsfiddle or something like that, demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Define "calculated differently."

Comment: Where are you trying to attach the image?  Do you have an example of what you are trying to do somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) value for buttons in Chrome (and Firefox) is `border-box`:

[image]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ET7G2/)

I.e. the total height, including padding (and border and margin), of the element is `30px`, not `50px` like for the link. You can fix this by setting

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```

explicitly.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ET7G2/1/)

[More info about the box model.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)

---

Why the `border-box` is the default value I cannot say. I haven't found a specification for it. Chrome, Firefox and Safari seem to do this (didn't test other browsers).

Comment: I've never used content-box for box-sizing and thought this was a great example, thank you!

Comment: This is very nice, but I can not use old browsers. T_T

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot use old browsers? You mean you cannot use that *rule* in old browsers? In that case, don't use `height`. See C.S.'s answer for an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20463948/218196.

Comment: @FelixKling box-sizing is css3, old browsers like ie6,7,8 can't understand box-sizing. I'm not speak English well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href...>
```

**Links** never have a set-height, if you inspect the html, you can see that; what is really done is giving it a **line-height** and **padding**.  when you write `height: 30px`, it is useless.

With respect to that, you **are** defining a height for the `<button>`, which is why it does not look the same as how you styled your link

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28fgQ/1/) to show how to make them the same, by removing the set-height of the `<button>`

Comment: `line-height` is often used together with `height` to vertically center the text content. Remove `line-height` and see the difference.